# Has it always been stackoverflo,ooo,ooow?

Tags: discussion

Has the logo for Stackoverflow always been "stack**overflo,ooo,ooow**"?

[image]

They did change that right? I'm not going crazy i hope.

Comment: Of course that is what it has always been ;) Now try and connect the temporary logo to the 10,000,000 questions...

Comment: ha, ok i guess if i moved my eyes down 50px i would see "Ten. Million. Questions."....so going crazy, just slowly lol

Comment: The ridiculous number of meta support questions that web page has generated does remind me a bit too much about how it got to 10 million.  I'll burn a candle.

Answer (score 3):

No, it wasn't always like this. They only changed it in the past few days to celebrate the 10 million questions mark.

Notice how `lo,ooo,ooo` looks like `10,000,000`. It's some word play on the site's name.